# Rules are Ignored in VehicleRouting with TimeWindows

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I took the example from Optaplanner to calculate optimal routes for a VRP with Timewindows and modefied the code a bit to satisfy our needs.

We have technicians who do work at a customers place.
Each of the technicians is it own "depot" because they can start at diffrent locations.
Each depot therefore has exactly one vehicle.

This works suprisingly well with the given example.

Now we want to add a rule that a technician should only be sheduled to a customer if he has the needed qualifications (for example only some technicians are allowed to drill)

The customer and the Technician both have qualifications that need to be matched.
We added a Rule in the drl file:

```
rule "qulificationcorrect"
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($vehicleQualifications:qualifications)
    $customer : Customer(vehicle==$vehicle,$customerQualification:qualifications)
    $test : Integer(RuleHelper.qualified($vehicleQualifications,$customerQualification)<1)
then
    System.out.println(RuleHelper.qualified($depotQualifications,$customerQualification));
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100L);
```

where Rulehelper looks like this:

```
public class RuleHelper
{
   public static int qualified(Integer[] vehicle, Integer[] customer)
   {
       if (customer == null || customer.length < 1)
       {
        System.out.println("CUSTOMER EMPTY");

        return 1;
       }
       if (vehicle == null || vehicle.length < 1)
       {
           System.out.println("VEHICLE EMPTY");

           return 0;
       }
       List<Integer> vehicleList = Arrays.asList(vehicle);
       List<Integer> customerList = Arrays.asList(customer);
       System.out.println("VehicleList=" + vehicleList + " CustomerList" + customerList + " rule = " + vehicleList.containsAll(customerList));
       return vehicleList.containsAll(customerList) ? 1 : 0;
   }
}
```

But when i look at my Solution it has no hardscore (0) and this is the output:

```
{
 "solutions" : [
   {
     "employee" : {
       "name" : "Technician 1",
       "qualifications" : [
         1,
         2,
         5,
         999
       ],
       "lat" : 49.70103,
       "lng" : 8.32404,
       "employeeId" : 31,
       "startTime" : 480,
       "endTime" : 1170,
       "maxOrderCount" : 0,
       "solutionId" : 1
     },
     "orders" : [
       {
         "qualifications" : [
           1000
         ],
         "transmittedStart" : 435,
         "transmittedEnd" : 660,
         "startTime" : 480,
         "endTime" : 540,
         "lat" : 49.96685,
         "lng" : 8.0308,
         "orderId" : 638411,
         "fixed" : false,
         "calculatedStart" : 522,
         "calculatedEnd" : 567,
         "solutionId" : 4
       },
       {
         "qualifications" : [
           999
         ],
         "transmittedStart" : 615,
         "transmittedEnd" : 840,
         "startTime" : 660,
         "endTime" : 720,
         "lat" : 49.89585,
         "lng" : 8.0809,
         "orderId" : 637001,
         "fixed" : false,
         "calculatedStart" : 583,
         "calculatedEnd" : 660,
         "solutionId" : 3
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "employee" : {
       "name" : "Technician 2",
       "qualifications" : [
         3,
         1000
       ],
       "lat" : 49.70103,
       "lng" : 8.32404,
       "employeeId" : 264,
       "startTime" : 480,
       "endTime" : 1170,
       "maxOrderCount" : 0,
       "solutionId" : 2
     },
     "orders" : [ ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Basically the first technician gets both orders (customers) although he has only the qualifications 1,2,5,999 and not 1000. The scound technician gets no orders instead of having the one with qualification 1000.

I hope that's enough informations for someone to tell me whats wrong...

King regards

EDIT: Thanks to the help of Geoffrey De Smet
I changed the Rule to

```
rule "qualificationcorrect"
when
    $customer : Customer(hasAllQualifications() == false)
then

    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100L);
```

end

and also implemented hasAllQualifications in Customer:

```
    public boolean hasAllQualifications()
{
    if (qualifications.length < 1)
    {
            return true;
    }
    if (vehicle == null || vehicle.getQualifications() == null || vehicle.getQualifications().length < 1)
    { 
        return false;
    }
    List<Integer> vehicleList = Arrays.asList(vehicle.getQualifications());
    List<Integer> customerList = Arrays.asList(this.getQualifications());
    return vehicleList.containsAll(customerList);
}
```

Now the solution shows the expected behavoir
Thanks again for the quick answer

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I am still wondering if your original code failed the FULL_ASSERT - this might point out a bug in drools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to how "incremental score calculation" works (which relies on calling `modify()` on drools facts). **Turn on `environmentMode` `FULL_ASSERT` - if it throws a score corruption exception this is the problem.**

If that's the case, let's take a look at your rule

```
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($vehicleQualifications:qualifications)
    // When the Customer.vehicle changes, the rule engine gets notified
    $customer : Customer(vehicle==$vehicle,$customerQualification:qualifications)
    // That should retrigger the evaluation of this line every time a customer's vehicle changes
    $test : Integer(RuleHelper.qualified($vehicleQualifications,$customerQualification)<1)
```

In any case, you might want to rewrite it like this anyway:

```
when
    $customer : Customer(hasAllQualifications() == false)
```

And just have `Customer.hasAllQualifications()` look at `Customer.vehicle`